# Connection timeout in ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc, connection-string

I know that I can set the connection timeout for MS SQL Server when using ADO or OLE DB, by adding *Connect Timeout=somevalue* to the connection string.

This doesn't seem to work for ODBC connections though. Specifically, we made the decision to use the standard SQL Server ODBC driver that ships with Windows XP (SQLSRV32.DLL version 2000.85.1132.00) instead of the newer SQL Native Client and it is with this driver that the connection always times out on 15 seconds, irrespective of the *Connect Timeout* setting.

Also, when it times out, I get two errors. The first is the timeout and the second is "Invalid connection string attribute" so I guess Connect Timeout is not what I need. The final clue that I'm missing the plot, came from this somewhat dated article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx

Does anyone know if there is a way to specifiy the connection timeout in the connection string for the standard SQL Server ODBC driver?

Comment: You know that there are 2 timeout related properties: ConnectionTimeout and CommandTimeout? Do you really have a problem when establishing a connection or already when executing a query?

Comment: The timeout occurs when establishing the connection through a VPN connection through DSL. Sometimes the connection happens quick enough and then the app is actually perfectly usable. But mostly the connection takes too long and it just times out. I reckon a 30 second timeout will be perfect, although I have obviously not been able to test that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the connection timeout by setting the SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT connection attribute with [SQLSetConnectAttr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713605(VS.85).aspx).

You can set the statement query timeout by setting the SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT statement attribute with [SQLSetStmtAttr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712631(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question.
Actually, just the moment I'm writing this, I checked the [SQLSetConnectAttr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms131709%28v%3dsql.110%29) and was surprisedly reading the first sentence

"The SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver **ignores** the setting of SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT."